# Unwanted zooming occurs with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, zooming, networkx

I am plotting a regular network **(1)** in its unaltered state and **(2)** in its altered state, meaning that a fraction of its nodes have failed.

The code I use to create and plot them is as follows.

**(1) Unaltered network:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N=100 #Number of nodes per grid side
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N) #Regular grid
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'pos', pos) #Store pos attributes in the nodes
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'labels', labels) #Store labels attributes in the nodes
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'),
                 labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'labels'),
                 with_labels=False, node_size=10)
plt.axis('off')
title_string=('Lattice Network') 
subtitle_string=(''+str(N)+'x'+str(N)+' = '+str(N*N)+' nodes | Average degree <k>: '+str(avg_degree_unaltered))
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)
plt.savefig('100x100_lattice.png', dpi=1000,bbox='tight')
plt.close()
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
```

**(2) Altered network:**

```
G2=dict((k, v) for k, v in status_nodes_model.items() if v < 1) #A special dict which holds the nodes that have failed due to a particular interaction
G.remove_nodes_from(G2) #We remove the failed nodes from graph G
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'),
                labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'labels'),
                 with_labels=False, node_size=10) 
plt.axis('off')
title_string=('Lattice Network, Stage 2') #Refers to step 11
subtitle_string=('Impact & dynamics | Active nodes: '+str(act_nodes_model)+' | Failed nodes: '+str(failed_nodes_haz+failed_nodes_model)+' | Total failure percentage: '+str(numpy.around(100*(failed_nodes_haz+failed_nodes_model)/10000,2))+'%')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)
plt.annotate('Event: '+file[6:12], xy=(0.5,0), xycoords=('axes fraction', 'figure fraction'), xytext=(0, 15), textcoords='offset points', size=8, ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.savefig(filelabel+'_100x100_lattice_stage2.png', dpi=1000,bbox='tight')
plt.close()
```

Note: as a result of the failures, network (2) has less nodes than network (1).

**My problem:** when I plot the two networks with **matplotlib**, I have a correct display for network (1) but an unwanted zoom is applied to the image of network (2) resulting in *stretched out shapes*.
**How can I avoid this and make sure that both networks are plotted at the same scale, that of network (1)?** Thanks!

**Images:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the limits of the first plot (before beginning plot 2)

```
xlim = plt.xlim()
ylim = plt.ylim()
```

and apply them to the second plot

```
plt.gca().set_xlim(xlim)
plt.gca().set_ylim(ylim)
```

Comment: There is a problem: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'`. Should I change the variable names to something like `xlim1` etc?

Comment: Ah my bad, `set_xlim` is actually a member of `Axes`. Try `plt.gca().set_xlim`